# how to achieve chart.js pie tips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

i want to achieve the tips,but i don't know how to configure in chart.js.
this is my code:

```js
var optionsPie = {
    responsive: true,
    animation: {
        animateScale: false
    },
    legend: {
        labels: {
            fontSize: 14,
            fontColor: '#000'
        }
    },
    defaultFontSize: 14,
    defaultFontColor: '#000',
    animateRotate: true,
    scales: {
        afterUpdate: function(obj) {
            console.log('afterUpdate', obj);
        }
    }
};
var type = 'pie';
var ctx = document.getElementById('chartBox');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: type,
    data: dataPie,
    options: optionsPie
});
```